# How to remove the index.html in cordova 3.9.2 for ios 7

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

This is the alert am displaying in cordova application

```
alert("welcome to all");
```

When i run the application in ios 7, it displays

```
index.html
welcome to all
```

To remove the `index.html` i have used cordova plugin  `cordova-plugin-dialogs`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",alert,false);
function alert(){
navigator.notification.alert("welcome to all");
}
```

but it's not working for me

Please let us know few details, to display the native alert in ios cordova application.

Note:
Here, Am not calling any native functionalities, completely the app developed in HTML,JavaScript only. Just we maintained all the content in `platforms/ios/www folder` . When i have started to run the app on iPhone 6 device or simulator it's showing the alert as per the https://www.dropbox.com/s/st5jpq4r0hq0fqk/alert.png?dl=0

Recently when i executed the app,
The message i have received

> The old format of this exec call has been removed (deprecated since
>   2.1). Change to: cordova.exec(null, null, "", "",[null,"Notification","alert",["HI am doing testing in alert","Good
>   Job1","Okay1"]]);

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, if any one knows please let use know some details

https://www.dropbox.com/s/st5jpq4r0hq0fqk/alert.png?dl=0

This is the image which am getting, but i want to display only message not page title

Comment: Why alert ? try to use Toast plugin : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: how did you install the plugin? only happens on ios 7?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have installed the plugin though command prompt 
cordova plugin add corodva-plugin-dialogs.

Comment: @AliEsmaeili, Thanks for your suggestion. As per your reference link i have implemented. It's working good.
but Client is asking for alerts only..
Please let us know any thing about this.

Comment: did you link the cordova.js file in your index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the title name loading in alert, 
We can also use another method by using custom plugins in javascript, so no need to use `cordova plugins`.

In my application i have used, `SweetAlert` plugin in javascript.

`SweetAlert` plugin you can download from this link 
        http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

It's very easy to integrate the plugin in our application.

After integration, just we can pass a message with this format

```
swal("Displaying new message using SweetAlert plugin");
```

Comment: Good Job,
Thanks for providing answer. It will be help full for other developers